# HP Pavilion g7 1012eo installed windows 8, cant turn on hardware virtualization

Tags: bios, hp-pavilion, hardware-virtualization

I have used my hp-pavilion g7 for almost one year. During this time i have developed apps for win7 phone. I never had any problem with the emulator.
I recently installed win 8 64bit pro on it to develop and test win8 apps. Now however the emulator for win phone doesnt work.
I realised that the problem was that hardware virtualization was turned off. All info i found referred to bios -> security and then turn it on.
However under my security all i can do is administrator password and power-on password.
I downloaded grc.com/securable to see and the program sais hardware virtualization is supported. There is no update for my BIOS on hp website.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Can it be fixed?

long story short: went from win7 64-bit home to win8 64-bit pro. Emulator in visual studio used to work, doesnt work anymore. Hardware virtualization not available under bios security.

edit: BIOS ver: HP F.03, 2011-03-16

Comment: Please add your extra info by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but if you're brave you can try this to enable advanced options in BIOS:
http://donovan6000.blogspot.com/2013/06/insyde-bios-modding-advanced-and-power-tabs.html